# React hook isn't updating data received from a fetch function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, fetch

The Text object continues to display "Pokemon" instad of `pokemon.name`. Any ideas?

```js
export default function App() {
  const getRandomPokemon = async () => {
    const randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 898);
    const uri = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${randomID}`;
  
    return fetch(uri)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      return {
        name: data.forms[0].name,
        height: data.height,
        weight: data.weight,
      };
    })
  }

  const [FirstCard, setFirstCard] = React.useState("Pokemon");

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CardStack 
      loop={true} 
      style={styles.cardStack}
      onSwipeStart={async () => {
        const pokemon = await getRandomPokemon();
        setFirstCard(await pokemon.name)
        console.log(pokemon)
      }}
      >
        <Card style={styles.card}><Text>{FirstCard}</Text></Card>
        <Card style={styles.card}><Text>2</Text></Card>
      </CardStack>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
});
```

Comment: why are you using `await pokemon.name`? shouldn't it be just `pokemon.name`?

Comment: Although some syntax elements are not necessary (as seen in my answer below), this code should basically work. See https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-vaughan-pn1uj?file=/src/App.js - which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `pokemon.name` is not a `Promise`. You should remove the `await` before `pokemon.name` in this case.

Comment: Didn't work. All the correct pokemon info is logged btw.

Answer (score 0):

it's a problem with the package you are using. see

[github.com/lhandel/react-native-card-stack-swiper/issues/76](http://github.com/lhandel/react-native-card-stack-swiper/issues/76)

---

you don't need to await for anything, just fetch and set the first card in the then function.

```
export default function App() {
  const [FirstCard, setFirstCard] = React.useState("Pokemon");
  const getRandomPokemon = () => {
    const randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 898);
    const uri = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${randomID}`;
    fetch(uri)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        setFirstCard(data.forms[0].name);
    })
  }
  useEffect(()=>{console.log(FirstName);},[FirstCard]);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CardStack 
      loop={true} 
      style={styles.cardStack}
      onSwipeStart={() => {
         getRandomPokemon();
     }}
      >
        <Card style={styles.card}><Text>{FirstCard}</Text></Card>
        <Card style={styles.card}><Text>2</Text></Card>
      </CardStack>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah it still doesn't work, could it have something to do with the card component I'm using? It's from an external node package.

Comment: add a useEffect to your code to see if the name gets updated. see updated code.

Comment: Yeah when I run the code w/```console.log(FirstCard)``` it prints out a pokemon name but the card still just says "Pokemon"

Comment: that means there's a problem with your Card component, which package are you using for that?

Comment: react-native-card-stack-swiper

Comment: it's a problem with the package you are using. see https://github.com/lhandel/react-native-card-stack-swiper/issues/76

Comment: @Wen W: if you like, write this as an answer and we can probably resolve the question.